# send email verification to another column in user table laravel

Tags: laravel, email-verification

I just want to send a laravel by default email verification on another db column laravel by default support email, but I just want to send on `temp_email` column.

Comment: try adding public function getEmailAttribute()
    {
        return $this->yourfieldname;
    }   in user model

Comment: @JohnLobo I can't do this i have two different column once is email and second one is temp_email, when user change their email then it will update temp_email column once he will verified then the email column will update.

Comment: What is your code? for example, Can you send email like this: `\Mail::to($user->email)->send(new VerifyMail($user));` .. Just change `$user->email` to `$user->temp_email `